# Browser behavior after location.replace

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser

I'm writing a piece of code that fires multiple image calls (pixels) and sometimes these calls can be latent based on server availability. I've devised a call where if all the calls aren't completed within 5 seconds, the page gets redirected via location.replace to an empty HTML page.

The whole thing is wrapped inside an iFrame and when i test it in Firebug, it seems to work well. When i look at the call in Fiddler, the time is shown as the full time the server took to reply (even though the browser was no longer waiting for the call).

What exactly is happening in the browser? Is it free to continue doing anything else it needs to? is it really still waiting for the call to come back even though the iframe has been changed via location.replace?

Let's assume this is the code in an iFrame, and the iFrame is placed on another page.

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="http://localhost:8080/MyServer/MyFirstCall" width="1" height="1"/>
    <img src="http://localhost:8080/MyServer/MySecondCall" width="1" height="1"/>
    <script>
        window.setTimeout("if(true) {location.replace('http://somewhere/empty.html');}", 5000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Firebug will tell me that everything is OK and the empty.html is loaded (of course i'm on debug and forcing the calls to be return after 5 seconds).

Fiddler on the other hand will tell me that the Overall Lapsed time on the FirstCall or SecondCall was 30seconds (or whenever i decided to let the debugger go).

Is the browser really waiting? Is it not waiting and is Fiddler just too smart and keeps track of calls even when they are no longer valid? Will other content continue to run or will the browser hold up the other things because the call hasn't technically returned?

Comment: I suspect it's just Fiddler keeping track of things. When a page is reloaded, all its asynchronous actions are cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

If the browser cancels the request, Fiddler also cancels the request.

The reason for the discrepancy is how browser-based tools like Firebug vs. proxy-based tools such as Fiddler work.  When you have something tracking requests in the browser, those tools only have the information that the browser makes available.  Lots of the lower-level information is completely lost.

Fiddler acts as a proxy server, so it is guaranteed to catch each request (assuming the browser is using the proxy server for all types of connections).  The data between the browser and the server flow through Fiddler.  However, the nature of having a proxy server may slightly alter behavior.  This is especially true for HTTPS requests where you must accept Fiddler's certificates.

If you want to know for sure what is happening, you need a packet sniffer which passively monitors the real data sent over the wire without modifying it.  I recommend Wireshark for this.  Then you will know for sure whether or not a connection is maintained.

Now for your specific issue... even if a connection were maintained beyond the time you were done with it, there probably isn't anything you can or should do about it.  Browsers are free to implement whatever methods they wish, in the interest of performance.  This often includes keeping connections open (HTTP Keep-Alive).